# OpenId Connect SwaggerUI C# snippet

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect, swagger-ui

I have added the following code to add authentication to my API. I am able to access my resources using postman, but I want to add it in Swagger UI also. As of now I am only getting blank Authorization box in the swagger UI. Am I missing or doing something wrong?

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
                options.Cookie.Name = "CookiE2";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,options => {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5002/";
                options.ClientId = "tapioauth";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret2";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.Scope.Add("roles");
                options.Scope.Add("galleryapi.fullaccess");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role","role");
            });

services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Auth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme{
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
                    Scheme = "openIdConnect",
                    Name = "OpenID Connect",
                    Description = "OpenID Connect Authentication",
                    OpenIdConnectUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:5002/.well-known/openid-configuration"), 
    
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Auth"
                            }
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            });
```

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => 
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
                    //c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "API v2");
                    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                });
```

Comment: I haven't tried oauth with swagger ui, but .... `Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows ...` ? https://www.camiloterevinto.com/post/oauth-pkce-flow-for-asp-net-core-with-swagger